No module named pip
Conda environment
I'm creating the following conda environment by conda env create -f environment.yml.
The environment.yml file content is:
name: deep3d_pytorch
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - pytorch=1.6.0
  - torchvision=0.7.0
  - numpy=1.18.1
  - scikit-image=0.16.2
  - scipy=1.4.1
  - pillow=6.2.1
  - pip=20.0.2
  - ipython=7.13.0
  - yaml=0.1.7
  - pip:
    - matplotlib==2.2.5
    - opencv-python==3.4.9.33
    - tensorboard==1.15.0
    - tensorflow==1.15.0
    - kornia==0.5.5
    - dominate==2.6.0
    - trimesh==3.9.20

Error
At the end of the environment creation process, these errors are thrown:
Installing pip dependencies: \ Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/usr/local/envs/deep3d_pytorch/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/content/Deep3DFaceRecon_pytorch/condaenv.i1gomfsb.requirements.txt', '--exists-action=b']
Pip subprocess output:

Pip subprocess error:
/usr/local/envs/deep3d_pytorch/bin/python: No module named pip

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed

In addition to conda env create -f environment.yml, updating the conda environment by conda env update -f environment.yml would throw similar errors.
Note
The errors occur on my local machine and also on the Google Colab. I'm just following the instructions. Does anybody have any clue or hint?
I have looked at this, but couldn't figure it out: Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment

I think the problem is that pip isn't installed. On a Debian-based system, try apt-get install python3-pip, or the equivalent for the package manager on your system.

Better let Conda then install pip, since Conda also installed Python for this environment: conda install pip. Keep it within the same environment, and then avoid the system installation. (To note: this Conda environment requires Python 3.6; the system pip may be for another Python version, and you'll end up installing incompatible packages.)

For some environments I strangely did not have it too. I used python -m pip install pip --force-reinstall

Note that the environment list does include pip. Makes me wonder if Conda ran the pip command before installing it, which I don't think it should do.

@9769953 Running conda install pip && conda env update -f environment.yml didn't help. The same errors are thrown.

A teammate helped me out:

I copy pasted your question into google gemini and it told me to do this :)

This change, suggested by Google Gemini, resolved the errors: I replaced - pip=20.0.2 with - pip on the environment.yml file:

Google Colab
On Google Colab I would run:
!sed -i '/- pip=20.0.2/c\  - pip' environment.yml
!conda env update -f environment.yml



That seems to suggest that Conda doesn't have a pip-20.0.2 package compatible with Python 3.6 (it does exist on PyPI, but Conda doesn't use that of course). Which means that whoever created the Conda environment file didn't check it properly (they might have upgraded pip through pip itself, which means the 20.0.2 isn't the version installed by Conda); or that the Conda package for pip 20.0.2 doesn't exist anymore.

@9769953 That's right. Makes sense.

Our final solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78425157/3405291
